# Common words having frequency more than in 2 file python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 files and I want to compare commonality. 
I am using dictionary to store frequency of words of 2 files. Now I want to find out words having more than frequency 1 and common in these 2 files.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post some code please; we aren't going to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you mean is words that appear in each file at least three times (going by "more than 2" in your title rather than "more than frequency 1" in the body of the post):

```
def frequent_common_words(frequencies_1, frequencies_2):
  frequent_words_1 = filter(lambda x: freqencies_1[x] > 2, frequencies_1.keys())
  frequent_words_2 = filter(lambda x: freqencies_2[x] > 2, frequencies_2.keys())
  return [word for word in frequent_words_1 if word in frequent_words_2]
```